# Windows Server 2016: How to create a website shortcut that opens in Edge?

Tags: hyperlink, virtual-machine, microsoft-edge, desktop, windows-server-2016

Edge not being my default browser, how do I create a **link that opens in Edge** on my Desktop in a **Windows Server 2016** VM?

Unfortunately, when I follow the instructions to create [custom URL shortcuts on desktop with Edge in **Windows 10**](https://superuser.com/questions/949998/windows-10-custom-url-shortcuts-on-desktop-with-edge), and I prepend the protocol *microsoft-edge* in the URL:

```
microsoft-edge:http://www.google.com
```

then I get a warning popup:

[image: Problem with Shortcut: The protocol "microsoft-edge" does not have a registered program. Do you want to keep this target anyway?]

Is this something that can be fixed on my side?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I ended up [setting up Edge as my default browser](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4028606/windows-10-change-your-default-browser) in the *Default app settings*, and editing my other [shortcuts so that they open in Internet Explorer](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b3013ff-e60f-490b-bbce-ab5e04d60906/how-to-force-shortcut-to-use-ie-when-not-default):

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.microsoft.com
```